# Build hangs when building Azure Function project (hangs on GenerateFunctions task)

Tags: build, azure-functions

run “dotnet build” - build hangs

here are the last lines from the build log file

```
              Task "GenerateFunctions" (TaskId:106)
                 Task Parameter:TargetPath=C:\xxxxx\xxxx\xxxx\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\bin\StoresLicenses.dll (TaskId:106)
                 Task Parameter:TaskAssemblyDirectory=C:\Users\XXXXX\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\3.0.11\build\..\tools\netcoreapp3.1\ (TaskId:106)
                 Task Parameter:OutputPath=C:\XXXXX\StoresLicenses\StoresLicenses\StoresLicenses\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\ (TaskId:106)
                 Function generator path: 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' (TaskId:106)
                 Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator.dll "C:\XXXXX\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\ " "False " (TaskId:106)
```

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot it?

Comment: Could you please share your code? Just cover the matter information.

Answer (score 0):

this problem is caused by setting the environment variable `COREHOST_TRACING` to `1`

Set `COREHOST_TRACING=0` and build will be executed correctly